# Compare two DataFrames, take a count based on given condition and update the existing count column

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I am learning Pandas and stuck in one problem, I am explaining the problem below with the sample example. 
Suppose there are 3 DFs. DF1, DF2 and DF3. I want to compare DF3 with DF1 and also with Df2 based on DF3 ID and Date column, where the Date falls between StartDate and EndDate, update the count in DF1 and DF2.

```
d = {'ID':['51','51','51','52'], 'Count' : ['2', '2', '1', '2'], 
 'StartDate' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-08-01']),
 'EndDate' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-08-31'])}

df1= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Count   EndDate        ID       StartDate
2       2018-09-30      51      2018-09-01
2       2018-07-31      51      2018-07-01
1       2018-08-31      51      2018-08-01
2       2018-08-31      52      2018-08-01

d = {'ID':['51','52'], 'Count' : ['5', '2'], 
 'StartDate' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-07-01', '2018-07-01']),
 'EndDate' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-30', '2018-09-30'])}

df2= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Count    EndDate    ID  StartDate
5       2018-09-30  51  2018-07-01
2       2018-09-30  52  2018-07-01

d = {'ID':['51','51','51','51','52'], 'Count' : ['1', '1', '1', '1','2'], 
 'Date' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-09-01', '2018-09-14', '2018-08-14', '2018-07-27','2018-08-13'])}

df3= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Count   Date    ID
1       2018-09-01  51
1       2018-09-14  51
1       2018-08-14  51
1       2018-07-27  51
2       2018-08-13  52

The expected output is DF1 and Df2 with updated count-
DF1 - 
Count   EndDate ID  StartDate
2       2018-09-30  51  2018-09-01
1       2018-07-31  51  2018-07-01
1       2018-08-31  51  2018-08-01
2       2018-08-31  52  2018-08-01

DF2-
Count   EndDate ID  StartDate
4       2018-09-30  51  2018-07-01
2       2018-09-30  52  2018-07-01
```

As it is observed DF1 count got updated to 1 for StartDate-'2018-07-01' and EndDate - '2018-07-31' since there was only 1 entry of month 07 in DF3.
Similarly, the overall(Quarterly) count changed from 5 to 4 in DF2. Please help me in solving this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `Count` columns to contain strings in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* the `Count` columns in your example code were specified as strings - I've converted them to integers.

I'm going to start with what I consider the best way to solve the problem of aggregating to different time periods: using the [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function with a date index:

```
data = df3.set_index('Date')
quarterly = data.resample('Q').sum()
monthly = data.resample('M').sum()
```

This results in

```
>>> quarterly
            Count
Date             
2018-09-30      6

>>> monthly
            Count
Date             
2018-07-31      1
2018-08-31      3
2018-09-30      2
```

You can even update this quite easily if new data become available:

```
newdata = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-03')], 'Count': [2]}).set_index('Date')
quarterly.add(newdata.resample('Q').sum(), fill_value=0)
```

If you really want to do this the way you have in the question, with given date ranges, this function does what you want in a simple way:

```
def updatecount(rangedf, countdf):
    for rowid, row in rangedf.iterrows():
        count = countdf.query('ID == @row.ID and @row.StartDate <= Date <= @row.EndDate').Count.sum()
        rangedf.loc[rowid, "Count"] += count
```

You would call it as

```
updatecount(df1, df3)
updatecount(df2, df3)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried updatecount function, it is giving problem with column sequence given in for statement. When i print the df, the seq of columns is changing. Can we fetch these columns in .query part in some other way?

Comment: instead of using column name directly, i gave rowid.ID and it worked for me.

Comment: @Jazz I've changed the answer to use `iterrows` which will not depend on the column order in the dataframes.